# Creating a simple user interface to access an Oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Here is what I have:
1) a simple sql file given to me that creates tables and fills them with data
2) a simple sql file that contains PL/SQL procedures I've written for displaying/manipulating the tables

The goal is to create some sort of user interface that allows a student to login, view their transcript, withdraw from classes, etc.

I am using sqlplus. I have procedures that do all the required displaying/manipulating. I am successful at creating a simple command line UI with sqlplus, but the problem arrives when I need to get user input inside a loop (for allowing them to see course information for any number of courses until they wish to go back to the main menu). After doing research, I learned that this would be the job of something like PHP, C, etc. Unfortunately, I am not proficient in any language required, and setting up extensions and such have proven to be extremely complicated.

I am capable of learning the necessary techniques to complete this, but I do not know which direction to go in. What is easiest to implement a simple UI? Should I use PHP? C? C++? Is there some sort of program out there that automatically creates simple UIs given database data?

Answer (score 9):

Oracle Apex is perfect for your situation. You can easily create web based forms and reports to perform all CRUD operations. Plus, it's free to use with any licensed Oracle database: [Oracle Application Express](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/overview/index.html)