# creating an interface using C++ for an oracle database

Tags: c++, database, interface

My question is if it is possible to create an interface using C++ (for windows) for accessing and inserting data into an Oracle database created with Oracle Database Express Edition. Somebody recommended me to use Java instead because "it is much simpler", or even .NET C#. But I know very little about Java. So, I would like to use C++ and some Windows API.
I read this: [Creating a simple user interface to access an Oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042771/creating-a-simple-user-interface-to-access-an-oracle-database) but I have to mention that for this project I'm not allowed to use APEX from Oracle. It must be an web application.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Look up [OCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Call_Interface).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to oracle DB through C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382984/connecting-to-oracle-db-through-c)